# How to disable flash messages from telecom carrier?

Tags: sms

I am having a Nokia 6.1 Plus running on Android 10.

I am facing this trouble while activating my bank on Google Pay. While the activation process, an SMS is sent. Then this flash message is shown regarding my SMS balance from the operator.

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

While this message is shown, the system gets out of context Google Pay. In return, Google Pay says this.

[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

I am irritated by this, sending or receiving money is trouble.

Answer (score 1):

These Class 0 messages are also called *flash messages*, that can be disabled by :

- Calling Airtel service and requesting (personal experience)
- On your device ([SOURCE that lists methods for other  Indian carriers also](https://www.geekdashboard.com/stop-flash-messages-on-android/))

> - Open SIM toolkit application and tap on Airtel Now! service. Now click on Start / Stop and select Stop to deactivate flash SMS completely.
> - In addition, you can also message STOP ANOW to 58234 to request the service deactivation.

Comment: Did you try the solutions?